# Re-open a closed case when a new comment is added

Tags: case, email2case

We are usinng Email-To-Case features and periodically, when clients do not answer to the thread, we close the cases.

It happened few times that the client answered later and we missed the client reaction, because the case was already closed. We tried to create a process with process builder on case comment, but we could not find a relation with the case record so to update the state.

How can we re-open the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom trigger on Case Comment object and you will get case Id in ParentId field of Case comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a process as shown below:

[image]